# How to convert JSON file nested arrays in CSV with jq

Tags: arrays, json, jq, export-to-csv

I'm new to JSON and Jq. I'm facing this problem.
With the REST APIs GET method a supplier give me data I need to feed my ERP's database with a JSON formatted file, like this

```
{
    "AWB":"04708222524",
    "flight":[
        {
            "id1":"TP00824 - 2023-04-21 19:35",
            "airline":"TP",
            "flightNumber":"00824",
            "dataOraArrivoVolo":"2023-04-21T19:35:00",
            "dataOraStimata":"2023-04-21T19:35:00",
            "dataOraEffettiva":"2023-04-21T20:06:00",
            "dataOraPartenzaVolo":null,
            "idCargoManifest":"CM202311107310",
            "HAWB":[
                {
                    "id2":"S03982804",
                    "numberPieces":1.0,
                    "dataOraRitiro":"2023-05-03T15:26:04",
                    "airline":"TP",
                    "airpComp":"MXP",
                    "tipoAllibramento":"T1",
                    "allibramento":"1365",
                    "dataAllibramento":"2023-04-21T00:00:00",
                    "dataOraSpunta":"2023-04-22T00:00:00",
                    "consolidata":"Y",
                    "mmaNote":null,
                    "mmaRegistroA3":"A3",
                    "mmaUfficioA3":"279100",
                    "mmaDataA3":"2023-04-21T00:00:00",
                    "mmaNumeroA3":"01911979",
                    "mrnPartita":"23ITQ0B316993302U0",
                    "itemPartita":1,
                    "mmaCinA3":"F",
                    "mmaStatoPartita":"SVINCOLABILE",
                    "mmaEsitoRettifica":null,
                    "mmaStatoRettifica":null,
                    "chargeableWeight":"108",
                    "docDogT1":null,
                    "serviziAggiuntivi":[
                        {
                            "spuntaUrgente":null,
                            "assistCarico":null,
                            "piombatura":null,
                            "visitaDogana":null,
                            "visitaRadiometrico":null
                        }
                    ],
                    "ubicazioni":[
                        {
                            "statoMerce":"RITIRATA",
                            "weight":108.0,
                            "ubicazione":null,
                            "codContenitore":null
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "result":"Ok",
    "resultMessage":""
}
```

I need to have it a CSV format like this

```
AWB,flight.id,flight.airline,flight.flightNumber,...,flight.HAWB.id2,flight.HAWB.numberPieces...
04708222524,TP00824 - 2023-04-21 19:35,TP,00824,...,S03982804,1.0,...
```

So what I need is to "flatten" the JSON file with nested arrays to a CSV file in a single line. Obviously if I have more than one i.e flight, the needed CSV structure will be something as this

```
AWB,flight.id,flight.airline,flight.flightNumber,...,flight.HAWB.id2,flight.HAWB.numberPieces...
04708222524,Flight-A,...,...,...,S03982804,1.0,...
04708222524,Flight-A,...,...,...,HAWB2,5.0,...
O4708222524,Flight-B,...,...,...,HAWBx,10.0,...
```

To do this I tried with jq, but my skills with this instrument are not enough. I obtained succesfully result with more simple JSON file, with no nested arrays...

I tried with something like this

```
jq -r -f .flight[0] | (map(keys) | add | unique) as $cols | map(. as $row | $cols | map($row[.])) as $rows | $cols, $rows[] |@csv FileIn.json >>FileOut.csv
```

but it doesn't work. As you can see I'm tryng with .flight[] because I'm not able to make jq consider the .AWB field as the first one...

So any help will be appreciated!